# Не переведён пункт Community Digests в настройках

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/email/digests/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил немного переводов:

> [image: переводы]